# Will I lose my domain name on AWS if I delete the hosted zone associated with it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-name

So I bought a domain name on AWS and it automatically created a Hosted Zone on Route 53 for my domain. I'm not using the domain anymore but I don't want to lose it. If I delete the auto-generated hosted zone, will it also delete my domain name? Or will I be able to create another hosted zone in the future?

Note that I want to delete the current hosted zone to save the monthly fee associated with it.....

Comment: Read important note from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DeleteHostedZone.html . This important note has answer to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will I lose my domain name on AWS if I delete the hosted zone associated with it?

No, you can delete the auto-generated one and configure your AWS registered domain to use other DNS providers, such as Cloudflare.

Comment: and what if I don't configure another DNS provider? I just want to pause my website for a few months and then resume it. I don't want to lose my domain in the meantime.

Comment: OK, found this: "In addition, if you delete a hosted zone, someone could hijack the domain and route traffic to their own resources using your domain name." So, I must use some DNS provider indeed...https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DeleteHostedZone.html